# A semi-colon with "however" vs. a comma with "but"

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

Is there any significant difference between these two sentences?

> Joseph created a few sets himself, **but the first** manufacturers who inspected his new game did not think it was likely to become very popular.
>
> Joseph created a few sets himself; **however, the first** manufacturers who inspected his new game did not think it was likely to become very popular.

I am wondering if using the semi-colon with *however* introduces any changes.

Answer (score 2):

"But" is treated as a conjunction, that joins two sentences together. This is often punctuated as

> ....., but .....

"However" is an adverb, and the sentence starts with "however".  But as these sentences are closely related you can link the two sentences with a semi colon, and puncutate:

> ......; however, ......

Many people use "however" as a conjuction, with a comma, but his use is "proscribed"; some educators and style guides recommend not to do this.

The meanings of your two sentences are functionally identical.